# Can we call a static iOS library from a Maui Project?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, maui

I was able to use a (.a) library in my xamarin project.

i used to add my static c++ library this way in the Xamarin.iOS project .csproj

```
      <ItemGroup>
    <NativeReference Include="Native References/MyLib.a">
      <Kind>Static</Kind>
      <ForceLoad>True</ForceLoad>
      <IsCxx>True</IsCxx>
      <SmartLink>True</SmartLink>
    </NativeReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

### in my Xamarin Project, every thing works fine :)

i tried to migrate the project to MAUI, I added the same functions, wrappers in my .NET Maui project... and i was not able to call the library

i tried first to add the same (.a) library in .csproj in this way ( Does not work )

```
  <ItemGroup>     
     <NativeReference Include="Platforms\iOS\libs\MyLib.a">
      <Kind>Static</Kind>
      <ForceLoad>True</ForceLoad>
      <IsCxx>True</IsCxx>
      <SmartLink>True</SmartLink>
    </NativeReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

then i tried this ( also does not work )

```
  <ItemGroup>     
  <ObjBindingNativeLibrary Include="Platforms\iOS\libs\MyLib.a"/>   
 </ItemGroup>
```

i don't find any documentation about this in microsoft Maui docs

is there any project or any sample or any docs about this ???

Answer (score 0):

I have my library in the root of my iOS Platforms directory: /Platforms/iOS/libCLib.iOS.a

Then in the projects file:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">
    <MtouchLink>Full</MtouchLink>
    <AdditionalArgs>-cxx -gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lCLib.iOS -force_load ${ProjectDir}/libCLib.iOS.a"</AdditionalArgs>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
    <NativeReference Include="Platforms\iOS\libCLib.iOS.a" Kind="Static">
        <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </NativeReference>      
</ItemGroup>
```

Important in the iOS Build settings: Linker behaviour for Debug has to be "Don't link" or "Link Framework SDKs Only".